# How to fix query returning to much data with search terms

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I am running a query to retrieve all customers of my data. Because of the new law not all customers have an address stored so i have some empty values. It works well if i run the "main" query retrieving all the customers left joining another table. When i try to add a search word it is still giving me the whole set instead of filtering it based on the search term. What did i do wrong?

I tried rewriting the query without the left join and just a WHERE c.customers_id = a.customers_id but because a.customers_id is not always filled i get way less customers than i have

```
select 
c.customers_id, c.customers_firstname, c.customers_lastname, c.customers_email_address, c.customers_account_validated, c.customers_payment_period, a.entry_country_id, a.entry_company 
from customers c 
left join address_book a on c.customers_id = a.customers_id 
and c.customers_default_address_id = a.address_book_id 
and (c.customers_lastname like '%adolfs%' 
or c.customers_firstname like '%adolfs%' 
or c.customers_email_address like '%adolfs%' 
or a.entry_company like '%adolfs%' or c.customers_id = 'adolfs') 
order by c.customers_id DESC
```

I expected a result of all customers with "adolfs" as firstname, lastname, company name, in the e-mailaddress

Comment: A group by without any aggregate functions is unlikely to be correct. If you are using group by as a deduper use select distinct instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
and (c.customers_lastname like '%adolfs%' 
or c.customers_firstname like '%adolfs%' 
or c.customers_email_address like '%adolfs%' 
or a.entry_company like '%adolfs%' or c.customers_id = 'adolfs')
```

These should be in a where clause not part of your join

```
select 
c.customers_id, c.customers_firstname, c.customers_lastname, 
c.customers_email_address, c.customers_account_validated, 
c.customers_payment_period, a.entry_country_id, a.entry_company 
from customers c 
left join address_book a on c.customers_id = a.customers_id 
and c.customers_default_address_id = a.address_book_id 
where c.customers_lastname like '%adolfs%' 
or c.customers_firstname like '%adolfs%' 
or c.customers_email_address like '%adolfs%' 
or a.entry_company like '%adolfs%' 
or c.customers_id = 'adolfs') 
group by c.customers_id 
order by c.customers_id DESC
```

That should work